# Microsoft Expression Web fails to publish - "The folder $FOLDER is contained by a server-based site."

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7

Some of our developers use Microsoft Expression Web to author their ASP and ASP.NET web applications. Our web servers are all built on Windows Server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5 and come in a group of separate Development, Testing and Production servers. The goal is for the developers to check out their source code to their workstation, then [publish](http://expressionwebstepbystep.com/?content=Chapter10) to Development, then Testing and then finally to Production using Expression. We are connecting with the web servers by exporting the IIS drives as file shares that the developers can then map or use in Expression. This works for one group of servers but not for another. When we try to publish from the Development server to the Testing server we get the following error:

[image: The folder is contained by a server-based site. To access this site you must use the http:// URL for the web server]

I'm not really sure how to interpret this error but I'm going to go with "the directory the file share is exposing to Expression is already being used by IIS as the location for a web site" which if that is a correct interpretation makes this feature pretty useless (wouldn't every website you'd want to publish to also be served by IIS?). I have tried looking through the Event Log on the server and compared the IIS configuration between the two server groups and cannot find anything immediately obvious. I would rather avoid the other connection methods (WebDAV, FTP, SFTP and Frontpage Extensions if possible).

How can I setup our web servers so our development teams can work on a website in Development and then publish it to Testing or Production without resorting to manually copying files or running a script? As someone who is not terribly familiar with Windows and IIS am I "just doing it wrong"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going to Microsoft's support for this. Here's what was going on:

At some previous point FrontPage was used to manage a site or sites within the main IIS directory (`W:\WWW\Development_Intranet`) on the Development Server (`IISDEV`). FrontPage keeps track of all its metadata with a number of files (see [List of Special Files and Directories Maintained by FrontPage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750050.aspx) for details) that were left in the directory. This causes Expression to detect that the site or a portion of it is managed by FrontPage and therefore invalidates it as a File System Publishing target; however we can't publish to the directory using the FrontPage Server Extensions (FPSE) because while the metadata files are still there the actual FPSEs are not installed since FrontPage has been depreciated since 2006.

The FPSE metadata files are not just limited to one "site" in the sense of your folder path. As I understand it, if somewhere further down the directory tree from `Development_Intranet\Unrelated_Site` there are leftover files, publishing to your site at `Development_Intranet\Site_I_Actually_Care_About` will fail since the whole thing is contained in a single IIS Site. We discussed writing a script that recursively descended through the directories deleting the FPSE metadata files however there is the danger that the sites still depended upon code and other other information stored on them. You can "de-couple" individual folders in Microsoft Expresson by [right clicking the site and selecting Convert to Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723902%28v=expression.40%29.aspx).

An additional concern is that Expression always tracks the full path for publishing so if we want to publish a file from `\\IISDEV\WWW\Development_IntranetSite_I_Actually_Care_About\test.html` to `\\IISTEST\WWW\Testing_Intranet\Site_I_Actually_Care_About\test.html`, what you actually end up with is your file being published to `\\IISTEST\WWW\Development_Intranet\Site_I_Actually_Care_About\test.html`. The whole idea of working in your Development server and then publishing to your Testing server only works for subsites as long as the full path is identical.

During our testing our support engineer and I noticed that Expression was slow when editing and manipulating files. Apparently every time you change directories, manipulate a site file or do some other action it "re-scans" the entire site directory. It sounds like it doesn't keep a cache and/or doesn't intelligently update it as you work with the site's files. Either way, he said for a site of our size (larger than 1GB) that we are pushing up against the performance limits of Expression and that we should not be surprised if it runs slow or crashes. Fantastic.

The final nail in the coffin here is that Microsoft Expression Studio was deprecated in 2010 and it's functionality has been rolled into Visual Studio 2012.